# Why I can not attach a JSON body to a GET request using Grails rest-client-builder plugin

Tags: json, rest, grails, testing, functional-testing

Trying to reach my REST endpoint the `request.JSON` is empty after executing this:

```
RestResponse response = rest.get("http://localhost:8080/${grailsApplication.metadata.'app.name'}/ws/question") {
    json([
        occurrenceId: 'f6f8a9b8-4d52-49c3-9352-155f154fc96c',
        userId: userKeef.alaUserId,
        tags: 'octopus, orange',
        comment: 'whatever'
    ])
}
```

but it works with a POST request: `rest.post(...`

Comment: have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get, ie get only sends url+querystring

Comment: Thanks Astra Bear! According to this you can send a body in a GET request. Although it is not a good practice -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Comment: maybe grails is protecting you from your dark thoughts?